# cts.estimate showing wrong document count

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

My requirement is get the count of total documents available in database.

```
cts.estimate(
  cts.trueQuery()
)
```

When I execute above query it is returning `1283265` document count but when I explore database from qconsole then document count is `1283262` so I am not sure about this document count mismatch.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And you are sure that content isn't changing (docs being added/removed)? Is it consistently different by the same amount of docs?

Comment: Yes @Mads Hansen no document is getting added or removed.

Comment: @MadsHansen 
Update - I tried using search:estimate(cts:true-query()) and it is returning same document count as shown in qconsole by exploring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you have some URIs in the database that do not have documents?

The code backing the Query Console explore button only reports the estimated number of documents:

```
let $total-doc := xdmp:estimate(doc())
```

The default behavior for `cts.estimate()` is to search for `any` fragment.

> Only one of "any", "document", "properties", or "locks" may be specified in the options parameter. If none of "any", "document", "properties", or "locks" are specified and there is a $query parameter, then the default is "document". If there is no $query parameter then the default is "any".

Run this query and verify what numbers are reported when explicit options are specified for estimates:

```
const estimate_default = cts.estimate(cts.trueQuery());
const estimate_any = cts.estimate(cts.trueQuery(), ["any"]);
const estimate_documents = cts.estimate(cts.trueQuery(), ["document"]);
const estimate_properties = cts.estimate(cts.trueQuery(), ["properties"]);
const estimate_locks = cts.estimate(cts.trueQuery(), ["locks"]);

[estimate_default, estimate_any, estimate_documents, estimate_properties, estimate_locks];
```

I would suspect that the difference in numbers is because of some URIs that do not have documents. It is possible, for instance, to have properties fragments for a URI and not have a document.

Comment: Thank you, @MadsHansen, 
Your query returned this output
[
1283265, 
1283265, 
1283262, 
3, 
0
]